# Как можно дописать этот код на GO?

Tags: windows, golang, сервер, domain, remote

помогите пожалуйста допилить скрипт до ума.
Этот скрипт написанный на GO позволяет подключиться по Remote Desktop Shadow к пользователям в домене.
Так вот, вот этот фрагмент кода выводит таблицу активных сессий пользователя.
Она выглядит вот таким образом.

```
 СЕАНС             ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ             ID  СТАТУС  ТИП         УСТР-ВО
 services                                    0  Диск
 console                                     8  Подключено
 rdp-tcp#52        Administrator             9  Активно
 rdp-tcp                                 65536  Прием
```

Можно ли дописать код так, чтобы он автоматически считывал эту таблицу, и если он находит в ней ячейку "Активно" по столбцу "Статус", он брал напротив этой строки ID, и помещал этот ID в самую последнюю строку скрипта.
Модифицировать этот скрипт таким образом, чтобы избежать ручного ввода ID сессии пользователя.

```
cmd1 := exec.Command("query", "session", "/server:" + rcomp)

cmd1.Stdout = os.Stdout

cmd1.Run()
```

Основной код

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    )
    
    func main() {
    var rcomp string
    fmt.Print("Введите IP-адрес или название ПК: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&rcomp)
    
    cmd1 := exec.Command("query", "session", "/server:" + rcomp)
    cmd1.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd1.Run()
    
    var rid string
    fmt.Print("Введите ID сессии: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&rid)
    
    cmd2 := exec.Command("mstsc", "/shadow:" + rid, "/v:" + rcomp, "/control")
    cmd2.Run()
    }
```